# What is difference between Discard() and Remove() function in python 3 sets

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code for discard and remove function in Python 3. Can anyone explain the difference?

remove() function :

```
num_set = set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  
 num_set.remove(0)  
 print(num_set)  
o/p
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

discard() function :

```
num_set = set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  
 num_set.discard(3)  
 print(num_set)  
o/p:
{0, 1, 2, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> `remove(elem)`: Remove element `elem` from the set. **Raises KeyError if
>   `elem` is not contained in the set.**
>
> `discard(elem)`: Remove element `elem` from the set if it is present.

That is: `remove` raises an error, `discard` not.

Answer (score 5):

It is useful to refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> remove(elem)
>
> ```
> Remove element elem from the set. Raises KeyError if elem is not contained in the set.
> ```
>
> discard(elem)
>
> ```
> Remove element elem from the set if it is present.
> ```

One of them will raise an exception when the element is not present, the other does not.